# How Should This be Coded The Right Way?

Tags: c++

I'm new to c++ and i'm learning on my own.
So my question is how should this be coded the right way?
Sorry if this sounds like a stupid question or if it's been answered already.

the problem is i'm trying to convert some of my batch files that i use daily to c++.
and i find myself using system(); a lot which i have read is wrong.

and would love to learn the right way before i start picking up bad habits.
so i'm asking if someone would rewrite this code the right way and break it down into details.
as so a person new to c++ can understand it better and as to why it should be done a certain way.

thank you in advance.

```
    #include <iostream>

    int main ()
    {
       system("title My Age Is?");
       system("mode con: cols=80 lines=25");
       system("color 0a");

       int myAge, yearBorn, yearNow;

       // the year you where born in.
       std::cout << "Enter the Year You where Born in:";
       std::cin >> yearBorn;
       system("cls");

       // the year it is now.
       std::cout << "Enter the Year it is Now:";
       std::cin >> yearNow;
       system("cls");


       // the total of Now - Then = ?
       myAge =  yearNow - yearBorn;

       // the output of Now - Then = ?
       std::cout << "You are " << myAge << " Years Old" << std::endl;
       std::cout << std::endl;
       system("pause");

    return 0;
    }
```

OK I think I'm getting closer to getting it right.
This is what I have so for.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <ctime>

    void cls( HANDLE hConsole )
    {
       COORD coordScreen = { 0, 0 };    // home for the cursor 
       DWORD cCharsWritten;
       CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi; 
       DWORD dwConSize;

       // Get the number of character cells in the current buffer. 

       if( !GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo( hConsole, &csbi ))
       {
          return;
       }

       dwConSize = csbi.dwSize.X * csbi.dwSize.Y;

       // Fill the entire screen with blanks.

       if( !FillConsoleOutputCharacter( hConsole,        // Handle to console         screen         buffer 
                                        (TCHAR) ' ',     // Character to write to the buffer
                                        dwConSize,       // Number of cells to write 
                                        coordScreen,     // Coordinates of first cell 
                                        &cCharsWritten ))// Receive number of characters written
       {
          return;
       }

       // Get the current text attribute.

       if( !GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo( hConsole, &csbi ))
       {
          return;
       }

       // Set the buffer's attributes accordingly.

       if( !FillConsoleOutputAttribute( hConsole,         // Handle to console screen buffer 
                                csbi.wAttributes, // Character attributes to use
                                dwConSize,        // Number of cells to set attribute 
                                coordScreen,      // Coordinates of first cell 
                                &cCharsWritten )) // Receive number of characters written
       {
          return;
       }

       // Put the cursor at its home coordinates.
       SetConsoleCursorPosition( hConsole, coordScreen );
    }

    int main()
    {
        // system("color 0a");
        int color = 0xa0;
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),color);

        /* using the void cls function to clear the screen instead of system("cls");
   but in this case i used it to clear the screen cache
   as set the text and background colors from above system("color 0a");
   using the void cls function */
        {
            HANDLE hStdout;
            hStdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
            cls(hStdout);
        }

        /* SetConsoleTitle(myAgeIs); to set the title of the console
        instead of system("title My Age Is?"); */
        char myAgeIs[] = "My Age Is?";
        SetConsoleTitle(myAgeIs);

        // the year you where born in.
        int yearThen;
        std::cout << "Enter the Year You where Born in:";
        std::cin >> yearThen;

        //using std::cin.get(); instead of system("pause");
        std::cin.get();

        // using the void cls function to clear the screen instead of system("cls");
        {
            HANDLE hStdout;
            hStdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
            cls(hStdout);
        }


        // used to get the system time now
        time_t t = time(0);
        struct tm * now = localtime( & t );

        // the total of current time - yearThen = ?
        int yourAge;
        yourAge = (now->tm_year + 1900) - yearThen;
        std::cout << "Your Age is " << yourAge;

        //using std::cin.get(); instead of system("pause");
        std::cin.get();
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Please read the documentation of `system` and C++ reference. That will definitely help you. First try yourself. After that if you faced any problem, we will help you.

Comment: You're claiming you seriously use a program (daily, no less?) to compute your age? Really?

Comment: no i have other batch files that i use.i just used this as example because it has the most system(); in it.

Comment: There's not much point writing a program in C++ if all it's doing is `system()` and simple input.  You're not going to learn much from it either.  Stick to batch files for this sort of thing, and choose something less trivial as your C++ practice program — something that'd utilize if/else, loops, and maybe writing a few functions.  How about a guess-the-number game as a starting point?

Comment: If you have to do this in C++, there's a console API as part of the Windows API that has also been built on already.

Comment: wow really all i did is ask a legit question that most new people to c++ want to know.and learn how to do it the right way that's all.i've also been learning if/if else/else for while and do while loops.sorry if i'm not an uber coder like most of you.but i'm trying to learn the right way and thats all.

Comment: thank you also chris i've been looking into the console api and it seems to be what i'm looking to this code with.

Comment: i hope to have this rebuild in a couple of days.i have all the information i need now i just need to figure how to piece it together.    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proper way to code is to eliminate the `system` function calls.  Use platform specific API for the functionality.

**Do you really need to clear the screen after each question?**
Doesn't seem very proper.  Some people like to look back at the previous output.  Also, doesn't work with windowing systems.

**Can age be negative?**
C++ has `int` type to handle negative numbers and `unsigned int` if the value will always be zero or positive.

**Check your input before calculating.**
For example, if the year born is greater than present year, you will present a negative age.

**Read year from OS.**
You don't need the User to input the present year.  Most platforms have clocks and functions to get the present time.

Comment: thank you for answering this is a good starting point.i don't know how to get the time from the system in to the program.

Comment: Search the web for "C++ get time".

Comment: ok thanks again got the time part will work it into the project.